# A svn branch is a full copy of trunk files or just a link?

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging

I mean what is the svn branch working principle.

When I create a branch, is there a real copy opertion accuring on the svn server, or just something like a file link is created?

Somebody knows this or maybe a little can give me a hand by own words, a book about svn or a website link.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion uses **cheap copies**. You can consider copy / branch or tag as a link. See [Cheap Copies section in SVNBook | Using Branches](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/using/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is realy helpful for me.